# Syntax error: "(" unexpected error while creating an openssl certificate using a bash command

Tags: bash, openssl

Using the instructions over [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-the-command-line) to define the SAN field inside the a `openssl` certificate, I am using the following commands to generate my own self-signed certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out domain.org.key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.org.key -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Acme, Inc./CN=*.domain.org" -out domain.org.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:domain.org,DNS:www.domain.org") -days 365 -in domain.org.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domain.org.crt
```

However, I am getting the following error:

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I don't see anything specifically wrong with the bash syntax used, could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error-message doesn't look like Bash to me; rather, Bash error-messages look like this:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I recommend double-checking that you're running these commands in Bash, and not a different shell. (Process substitution isn't specified by POSIX, so not all shells support it.)

If it turns out that Bash is not available, you can use a temporary file:

```
printf "subjectAltName=DNS:domain.org,DNS:www.domain.org" > tmp-ext-file
openssl x509 -req -extfile tmp-ext-file -days 365 -in domain.org.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domain.org.crt
```

or standard input:

```
printf "subjectAltName=DNS:domain.org,DNS:www.domain.org" \
| openssl x509 -req -extfile /dev/stdin -days 365 -in domain.org.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domain.org.crt
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer! It turned out that I was using a default `zsh` shell, and forgot to switch back to `bash`. Thanks so much!

Comment: @QPTR: My pleasure! But that's odd, because Zsh *does* support process substitution: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Process-Substitution. (I don't know enough about Zsh to know why that might not be working for you.)